# [groovy] collada parser source incomplete

Tags: ros, include, collada, source, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing groovy from source.

```
$ sudo wstool init src -j8 http:/packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/robot

$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
```

Compilation fails at collada_parser because of missing dae.h

Looking at the Fuerte install on my laptop, colladadom includes contain a host of different files missing from the groovy raw.

Copying dae.h prompts for another missing file: dom/domCOLLADA.h.

Now there are two possibilities: either copying the dom folder inside the 1.4 subfolder, or the one inside 1.5.
The one in 1.4 causes make to output a three pages long series of errors.
The one in 1.5 fails because of a missing namespace 'ColladaDOM150'.
Commenting out this line (number 75 of the single source file) compilation proceedes succesfully for this package.

Next is collada_urdf which suffers from the same missing includes and wrong namespace.
So I copied both dae and dom the same way I did before, but this time make outputs lots of undefined references to collada functions.

I think this is a bug, but I couldn't find how to submit to the tracker (no ticket link on the package's page).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53074/%5Bgroovy%5D-collada-parser-source-incomplete/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-01-22

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-22**:
Tracker is here https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-01-22**:
Thanks, doesn't accept my code.ros.org login though...

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-26**:
Try reloading after entering the credentials and waiting a bit.  The website is very sluggish at the moment.  That's why we're migrating off of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you will need to install collada-dom separately

```
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/collada-dom/files/latest/download
$ tar -xf download
$ cd collada-dom-2.4.0
$ cmake . && make install
```

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-01-29**:
thanks, I'll try that on the Panda.
I tried on my x64 machines, but I get errors on some zip64 functions.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-04**:
for your x64 machine, I would recommend using the prebuilt binaries

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2013-03-09**:
Installing this from source does not solve the problem. At least, not on my Beagle Board xM. I still get a compilation error with dae.h missing. If I had a copy of dae.h, where would I place it?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-10**:
just copying dae.h will not solve your problem. You need to make sure collada-dom is found by collada_parser. Have a look at this guide on how to install it http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Linaro/Source

**Comment by [xaedes](https://answers.ros.org/users/6307/xaedes/) on 2016-01-02**:
if anyone has still dae.h missing errors, try this: https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Claudio,

I was having the same issue and just fixed it.

If, like me, you installed the collada-dom library from sources **after** catkin failed to build collada_parser,
you have to **delete** your current catkin installation and start over
(to remove the CMakeCache that couldn't locate the collada-dom headers the first time, and which doesn't get updated when you re-runn the catkin command).

maybe adding --force-cmake to the catkin command would force CMake to update its cache, I haven't tried it.

---

Originally posted by [Nicolaje](https://answers.ros.org/users/2923/nicolaje/) with karma: 31 on 2013-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [collada](https://answers.ros.org/users/5317/collada/) on 2013-07-04**:
Thanks!

**Comment by [yagamiram](https://answers.ros.org/users/22787/yagamiram/) on 2015-07-19**:
As you said, --force-cmake works like charm ! No need to delete the cmake installation.

**Comment by [Imesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31664/imesh/) on 2018-01-19**:
In anycase,If you dont know where to add --force-cmake (Yes, we exists :) ;) )
in Kinetic installation of rasbian jessie this worked. Thanks..

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --force-cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic -j2
```